# Getting value from json object

Tags: ajax, json

I am unable to retrieve values from json object.The json data as coming like this when observe from firebug :

```
[{"PROJECT_ID":"CASEENO"},{"PROJECT_ID":"DARKROOM-2"}]
```

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getdata.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 'dataString': projectid }, cache:false,
    success: function(data)
             { 
                  alert(data);
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                  {             
                     $("#projid").append("<option value=data[i].PROJECT_ID>data                  [i].PROJECT_ID</option>");
                   }   
             }
});
```

alert(data) is giving [object Object].
I tried like this `data.PROJECT_ID, data[PROJECT_ID],data[i].PROJECT_ID` but project id value is not displaying in select tag.
How can I retrieve project id from for loop?

Answer (score 1):

If `alert(data)` gives `[object Object]`, then `data` is not an array. It should output `[object Object],[object Object]`.

I recommend to use `console.log(data)` to get a better idea of what `data` actually is and to examine its structure. This question might help you too: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value).

Assuming `data` is indeed an array, to use its values in the HTML string you have to use string concatenation:

```
$('#projid').append('<option value="' + data[i].PROJECT_ID  + '">' + data[i].PROJECT_ID + '</option>');
```

or create the element differently:

```
$('<option />', {
    value: data[i].PROJECT_ID,
    text: data[i].PROJECT_ID
}).appendTo('#projid');
```

JavaScript is **not** interpolating strings like PHP does.

Answer (score 1):

Change your statement 
from

```
 $("#projid").append("<option value=data[i].PROJECT_ID>data[i].PROJECT_ID</option>");
```

to

```
$("#projid").append("<option value="+data[i].PROJECT_ID+">"+data[i].PROJECT_ID+"</option>");
```